# qemu to emulate SD-Bus and card

Tags: qemu, kvm

I am trying to mount a drive image emulated as an SD card with qemu-system-x86_64.
qemu tells me that it is not supported by the machine type, can this really be true?

My command looks like this

```sh
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cores=4 -m 1024 -sd sdcard.qcow2 boot.img
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'boot.img' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
qemu-system-x86_64: -sd sdcard.qcow2: machine type does not support if=sd,bus=0,unit=0
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an SD controller:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cores=4 -m 1024 -device sdhci-pci -device sd-card,drive=mydrive -drive id=mydrive,if=none,format=raw,file=image.bin`

[Source](http://qemu.11.n7.nabble.com/Mounting-an-sdcard-on-x86-tp713176p713187.html)